# How to export everything useful in my iTerm to another system

Tags: macos, import, export, iterm2

I am currently using iTerm2 3.4.4 on my macbook pro. I am getting a different macbook and would be installing iterm on that one as well.

I want to export as much as possible from the older machine and import it into the new one. Some things I can think of it profile settings, command history, etc. How can I export these things and import them in the new machine ?

Is there an iTerm folder I can just copy and paste ?

Answer (score 2):

You can export your profile by going to Settings - Profiles, then go to other actions and then Save Profile as JSON. You could copy the whole /Users/yourusername/Library/Application Support/iTerm2 folder to your new machine, which probably works as well. The command history depends on the shell that you're using, it has nothing to do with iTerm.
Bash History: ~/.bash_history
Zsh History: ~/.zsh_history
Fish History: ~/.local/share/fish/fish_history
The shell configurations depend on your shell as well.

Answer (score 2):

The current stable version of iTerm2 (3.4.19) looks like it stores preferences settings in

- `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.plist`
- `~/Library/Preferences/com.googlecode.iterm2.private.plist`

by default, unless you use the option in Preferences ▹ General ▹ Preferences to save it to a custom location:

[image]
State information is stored separately in `~/Library/Application Support/iTerm2/` as noted in @techrisdev's answer of 2021-04-20.